# How to put the buttons above the image (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to place some buttons with specific positions above an image within a carousel of images through a html/css code. I have taken a look at different posts but I can not solve my problem.
This is my **HTML code**:

```
<!-- This is the image on which I want to put the buttons -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
       <img src="<?= Vector_url[7][1] ?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="Nope">

      <!-- Buttons container to download PDFs -->
       <div class="container" id="fila1">
        <div class="row" id="cajas1">
          <a class="btn btn-primary col" href="<?= Vector_Survey[25][1] ?>" role="button" target="_blank" >MSN087</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary col" href="<?= Vector_Survey[26][1] ?>" role="button" target="_blank" >MSN089</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

And this is my **CSS code:**

```
img {
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-height: 90%;
        max-width: 90%;
        z-index:-1;
    }
div {
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
.container{
  z-index:100;      
          }
.carousel-item{
  z-index:-1;
  background-size: cover;
              }
/* Buttons Style */
.btn {
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
  border:white;
  margin:10px;
  padding:-10px;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-weight:bold;
  max-width:90px;
  height:30px;
  margin-right:22px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

I don´t know if i have something wrong on my code or maybe i'm missing something but the buttons appear behind the image and i want the opposite.

Thanks you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need `position: absolute` or `position: fized` or `position: relative`.
You could add `position: relative` to your button's CSS properties to make it work the way you want.
By default, all elements have their position to be `static`. Elements with position of `static` do not respect `z-index` and `z-index` is ignored. This is why your `z-index` wasn't working.

EDIT:
Found what's your problem. Give your image a property `position: absolute`. This should screw it's positioning up, but, your problem would be solved and you can use flexbox to align them properly again. Now your buttons are in over the image (if we see from third dimension). Check out [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/sarveshmd/pen/NWgxmVG) I created to work on this problem.

Comment: `position: fixed;`*

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned and I still can't put the buttons in the front of the image...

Comment: I've updated the answer and this should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of adjusting the button position by changing the margin and padding

Try to use `position: absolute;` and `top: ;` and also `left: ;` commands to adjust the position.

If you are wondering why your `z-index` is not working, it is because all objects by default are assigned `static`position and the position `static` ignores the `z-index`

Comment: Ok, I understand the mechanics of the relationship between positions, but even modifying the type of position of each element, it still does not work as I would like.  i used `position:absolute;z-index:999;` on .btn and `position:relative; z-index:1;` to .img and then positioned the buttons with `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` (to see if it works on this possition) and nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

In order to put a button on top of another element (image/carousel) in your case, you  should put `position:relative; z-index:1;` to your .container class and `position:absolute;z-index:999;` to your .btn class.
After that you have to position your buttons more precisely by just moving them with left/right/top/bottom attributes.
Z-index - the higher the index, the more privilege it has among other elements. So if you want to put buttons on top of an image, you should do as I sad, buttons with higher index, images with lower index.

Comment: I did what you say, but it keeps putting the buttons behind the image... i used `position:absolute;z-index:999;` on .btn and `position:relative; z-index:1;` to .img and then positioned the buttons with `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` (to see if it works on this possition) and nothing happens... Maybe im missing something with the structure of the code or something like that.

Comment: Check [this](https://codepen.io/leoxramadani/pen/dyRGYXp) example I did right now, it should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Your example. One of the ways is to give Your `button` element `position: absolute` and to give `position: relative` to his closest parent. After that You will be able go give Your button more specific positioning.

Take a look at the below link with the example.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_on_image.asp

**NOTE: Please be aware that this site (according to  me) is not the best source of knowledge but the example shown there is relevant to Your problem.**

Comment: There must be something else wrong with my code becouse even changing the position style of all elements (buttons position absolute and image position relative) it keeps not doing what i want...